# how do I reactivate the 3d manipulator?

Tags: mesh

Every time I select an axis on the 3d-manipulator and try to drag my selection, the 3d-cursor is placed where I click, but no transform takes place.  If I select a previous version of the file, there's no problem, and the manipulator works the way it should.
I probably hit the wrong shortcut key by accident, and I have no idea how to undo it.  Selecting and deselecting the manipulator (in other words, turning it off and on again) doesn't work.
If anyone knows how to sort this out, please help, as it's probably something stupid.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of the situation?

Comment: perhaps you've locked your object? (in 3D view, panel activated if your press N, then the Transform menu...

Comment: Try pressing the other click on the mouse. By default, you can drag and move object by manupulator with the right click and place the 3D cursor by left click. If this doesn't work, post a screenshot of your problem.

Comment: The problem is view-orientated.  The manipulator works properly in camera-view for some reason, but not in any other views.